# Black screen after run application created using javaFxports

Tags: android, javafx-8, javafxports

I have problem with compilation my application. When .apk file is beeing compiled IDE should downolad dalvik.sdk or plugin javaFxports. In my case he doesn't do this. Below I present information from my console:

```
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Starting Gradle build for the following tasks: 
[sts]      android
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
:validateManifest
:collectMultiDexComponents
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileAndroidJava UP-TO-DATE
:copyClassesForRetrolambda
:applyRetrolambda
Retrolambda 2.3.0
Bytecode version: 50 (Java 6)
Default methods:  true
Input directory:  C:\Users\Orden\workspace2\SQLiteTest\build\javafxports\tmp\android\retrolambda\input
Output directory: C:\Users\Orden\workspace2\SQLiteTest\build\javafxports\tmp\android\retrolambda\output
Classpath:        [C:\Users\Orden\workspace2\SQLiteTest\build\javafxports\tmp\android\retrolambda\input, C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar]
Included files:   all
Agent enabled:    false
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/layout/Layer$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/c$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonapplication/BasicView$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonapplication/BasicView$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonapplication/BasicView$$Lambda$3
Saving lambda class: com/gluonapplication/BasicView$$Lambda$4
Saving lambda class: com/gluonapplication/BasicView$$Lambda$5
Saving lambda class: com/gluonapplication/BasicView$$Lambda$6
Saving lambda class: com/gluonapplication/BasicView$$Lambda$7
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/a$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/ExpansionPanel$ExpandedPanel$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/ExpansionPanel$ExpandedPanel$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/application/GlassPane$1$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/b$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/connect/provider/FileClient$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/application/GlassPane$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/application/GlassPane$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/application/GlassPane$$Lambda$3
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/application/GlassPane$$Lambda$4
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/connect/gluoncloud/ObjectDataSkel$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/layout/layer/MenuPopupView$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/layout/layer/MenuPopupView$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/i$a$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/android/AndroidLifecycleService$AndroidActivityLifeCycle$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/DatePicker$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/DatePicker$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/connect/gluoncloud/GluonCloudLocalObjectDataWriter$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/connect/gluoncloud/GluonCloudLocalObjectDataWriter$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/connect/gluoncloud/GluonCloudLocalObjectDataWriter$$Lambda$3
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/connect/gluoncloud/GluonCloudLocalObjectDataWriter$$Lambda$4
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/connect/gluoncloud/GluonCloudLocalObjectDataWriter$$Lambda$5
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/layout/layer/SnackbarPopupView$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/layout/layer/SnackbarPopupView$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/layout/layer/SnackbarPopupView$$Lambda$3
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/layout/responsive/grid/GridRow$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/layout/layer/MenuSidePopupView$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/a$a$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/a$a$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/a$a$$Lambda$3
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/b$1$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/NavigationDrawer$ViewItem$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/c/a$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/c/a$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/connect/gluoncloud/metadata/ConnectMetadataClass$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/layout/layer/SidePopupView$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/layout/layer/SidePopupView$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/layout/layer/SidePopupView$$Lambda$3
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/layout/layer/SidePopupView$$Lambda$4
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/connect/converter/ClassInspector$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/connect/gluoncloud/GluonCloudListReaderImpl$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/connect/gluoncloud/GluonCloudListReaderImpl$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/connect/gluoncloud/GluonCloudListReaderImpl$$Lambda$3
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/connect/gluoncloud/GluonCloudListReaderImpl$$Lambda$4
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/connect/gluoncloud/GluonCloudListReaderImpl$$Lambda$5
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/connect/gluoncloud/GluonCloudListReaderImpl$$Lambda$6
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/connect/gluoncloud/GluonCloudListReaderImpl$$Lambda$7
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/connect/gluoncloud/BatchListObjectDataProcessor$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/connect/gluoncloud/BatchListObjectDataProcessor$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/connect/gluoncloud/BatchListObjectDataProcessor$$Lambda$3
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/connect/gluoncloud/BatchListObjectDataProcessor$$Lambda$4
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/b/a$4$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/b/a$4$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/b/a$2$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/b/a$2$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/b/a$2$$Lambda$3
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/mvc/SplashView$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/mvc/SplashView$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/mvc/SplashView$$Lambda$3
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/TimePicker$a$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/TimePicker$a$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/TimePicker$a$$Lambda$3
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/TimePicker$a$$Lambda$4
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/TimePicker$a$$Lambda$5
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/TimePicker$a$$Lambda$6
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/f$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/f$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/f$$Lambda$3
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/f$$Lambda$4
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/f$$Lambda$5
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/f$$Lambda$6
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/f$$Lambda$7
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/f$$Lambda$8
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/f$$Lambda$9
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/f$$Lambda$10
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/f$$Lambda$11
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/f$$Lambda$12
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/f$$Lambda$13
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/f$$Lambda$14
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/f$$Lambda$15
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/f$$Lambda$16
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/f$$Lambda$17
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/f$$Lambda$18
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/f$$Lambda$19
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/f$$Lambda$20
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/f$$Lambda$21
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/h$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/h$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/h$$Lambda$3
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/h$$Lambda$4
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/g$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/g$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/g$$Lambda$3
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/c$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/TimePicker$c$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/TimePicker$c$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/TimePicker$c$$Lambda$3
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/TimePicker$c$$Lambda$4
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/TimePicker$c$$Lambda$5
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/TimePicker$c$$Lambda$6
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/TimePicker$c$$Lambda$7
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/b$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/b$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/b$$Lambda$3
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/b$$Lambda$4
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/d$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/d$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/c/a$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/c/a$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/layout/responsive/grid/GridSpan$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/p$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/p$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/p$$Lambda$3
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/p$$Lambda$4
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/p$$Lambda$5
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/o$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/o$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/j$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/j$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/j$$Lambda$3
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/connect/provider/DataProvider$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/connect/provider/DataProvider$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/connect/provider/DataProvider$$Lambda$3
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/connect/provider/DataProvider$$Lambda$4
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/connect/provider/DataProvider$$Lambda$5
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/connect/provider/DataProvider$$Lambda$6
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/connect/provider/DataProvider$$Lambda$7
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/connect/provider/DataProvider$$Lambda$8
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/connect/provider/DataProvider$$Lambda$9
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/connect/provider/DataProvider$$Lambda$10
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/connect/provider/DataProvider$$Lambda$11
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/connect/provider/DataProvider$$Lambda$12
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/connect/provider/DataProvider$$Lambda$13
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/connect/provider/DataProvider$$Lambda$14
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/connect/provider/DataProvider$$Lambda$15
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/connect/provider/DataProvider$$Lambda$16
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/connect/provider/DataProvider$$Lambda$17
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/connect/provider/DataProvider$$Lambda$18
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/connect/provider/DataProvider$$Lambda$19
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/connect/provider/DataProvider$$Lambda$20
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/i$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/connect/gluoncloud/GluonCloudUpdateFieldReader$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/connect/gluoncloud/GluonCloudUpdateFieldReader$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/l$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/l$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/l$$Lambda$3
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/v$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/u$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/u$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/u$$Lambda$3
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/u$$Lambda$4
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/u$$Lambda$5
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/AutoCompleteTextField$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/AutoCompleteTextField$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/r$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/r$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/r$$Lambda$3
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/r$$Lambda$4
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/Dialog$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/Dialog$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/Dialog$$Lambda$3
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/Dialog$$Lambda$4
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/Dialog$$Lambda$5
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/Dialog$$Lambda$6
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/Dialog$$Lambda$7
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/Dialog$$Lambda$8
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/Dialog$$Lambda$9
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/t$$Lambda$1
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/t$$Lambda$2
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/t$$Lambda$3
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/t$$Lambda$4
Saving lambda class: com/gluonhq/impl/charm/a/b/a/s$$Lambda$1
.................................................................................................................
:mergeClassesIntoJar
:shrinkMultiDexComponents
:createMainDexList
:writeInputListFile
:dex
:mergeAndroidAssets
:mergeAndroidResources
Crunching single PNG file: C:\Users\Orden\workspace2\SQLiteTest\src\android\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png
    Output file: C:\Users\Orden\workspace2\SQLiteTest\build\javafxports\tmp\android\resources\res\mipmap-mdpi-v4\ic_launcher.png
Crunching single PNG file: C:\Users\Orden\workspace2\SQLiteTest\src\android\res\mipmap-ldpi\ic_launcher.png
    Output file: C:\Users\Orden\workspace2\SQLiteTest\build\javafxports\tmp\android\resources\res\mipmap-ldpi-v4\ic_launcher.png
Crunching single PNG file: C:\Users\Orden\workspace2\SQLiteTest\src\android\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher.png
    Output file: C:\Users\Orden\workspace2\SQLiteTest\build\javafxports\tmp\android\resources\res\mipmap-hdpi-v4\ic_launcher.png
Crunching single PNG file: C:\Users\Orden\workspace2\SQLiteTest\src\android\res\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png
    Output file: C:\Users\Orden\workspace2\SQLiteTest\build\javafxports\tmp\android\resources\res\mipmap-xhdpi-v4\ic_launcher.png
Crunching single PNG file: C:\Users\Orden\workspace2\SQLiteTest\src\android\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher.png
    Output file: C:\Users\Orden\workspace2\SQLiteTest\build\javafxports\tmp\android\resources\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi-v4\ic_launcher.png
Crunching single PNG file: C:\Users\Orden\workspace2\SQLiteTest\src\android\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png
    Output file: C:\Users\Orden\workspace2\SQLiteTest\build\javafxports\tmp\android\resources\res\mipmap-xxhdpi-v4\ic_launcher.png
:processAndroidResources UP-TO-DATE
:processAndroidResourcesDebug
:validateSigningDebug
:apkDebug
:zipalignDebug
:android

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2 mins 41.36 secs
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Build finished succesfully!
[sts] Time taken: 2 min, 42 sec
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
```

After instalation on my phone with android OS when I run application I see only black screen.

Below I present my build.gradle file script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.1.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.0.0'


    // Desktop SQL -> https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc
    desktopRuntime 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.8.11.2'

    embeddedRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-plugin-storage-desktop:3.0.0'
    // Embedded SQL -> https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc
    embeddedRuntime 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.7.2'

    // Android SQL -> https://github.com/SQLDroid/SQLDroid
    androidRuntime 'org.sqldroid:sqldroid:1.0.3'

    // ios SQL -> https://github.com/robovm/robovm 1.8
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.0.0'
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        androidSdk = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*',
                'SQLite.**.*'
        ]
    }
    embedded {
        remotePlatforms {
            raspberry {
                host = '192.168.1.10'
                username = 'pi'
                password = 'raspberry'
                workingDir = '/home/pi/Gluon'
                jreLocation = '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt'
                execPrefix = 'sudo'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Build finished successfully` means that the `android` task ended successfully, that's why you could install it later on your phone. A black screen means that when it starts there is an exception. First check that on your desktop it runs correctly. Then go to your Android sdk folder, enter into platform-tools and run `adb logcat -v threadtime` with your phone connected, run the app and check the console for the exception. When you find it, try to solve the issue or post the stacktrace here.

Comment: On my deskop it works ok. Now I check apk file using Android sdk